# Vim regex erasing everything between colon and a space or a newline

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to use vim regex to erase everything after a colon `:` and a space or newline character.  Below is the text that I'm working with.

```
ablatives       ablative:ablative_A s:+PL
abounded        abound:abound_V ed:+PAST
abrogate        abrogate:abrogate_V
abusing ab:ab_p us:use_V ing:+PCP1
accents'        accent:accent_N s:+PL ':+GEN
accorded        accord:accord_V ed:+PAST
```

So what I want to get from this is the following:

```
ablatives       ablative s
abounded        abound ed 
abrogate        abrogate
abusing ab us ing
accents'        accent s '
accorded        accord ed
```

I'm pretty lost on this one but I did trying the statement below:

```
:s/\:. / /g
```

I'm trying use that to get at least one of the patterns that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to give the results you want:

```
:%s/:.\{-}\([ \n]\)/\1/g
```

- `:` – literal `:`. I'm not sure why you escaped that in your question, since you don't need to.
- `.` – mach any character.

  - `\{-}` – repeated zero or more times as little as possible ("ungreedy", like `*?` in many other regexp engines).
- `\(` – start new subgroup for the reference in the replacement pattern.

  - `[` – start "match any of these characters.

    - – literal space.
    - `\n` – newline.
  - `]` – end `[`.
- `\)` – end subgroup.

In the replacement pattern we use `\1` to insert either a space or newline, depending on what we replaced.

You can also use `\_s` instead of `[ \n]`, this will match all spaces, tabs, and newlines. I personally prefer `[ \n]` since that's more portable across regexp engines (whereas `\_s` is a Vim-specific construct).

see `:help <atom>` for more information on any of the above.

Answer (score 3):

**Simply**, you can do :

```
:%s/:\S*//g
```

---

> **`\S`**      non-whitespace character;

Answer (score 0):

```
:%s/:[^ ]*//g
```

This deletes `:` followed by zero or more non-space characters. Newline character at end of line won't be affected